SQL server granular control over auto update statistics
I wanted to know if we get more granular control over auto update statistics at the index level in SQL server.
One of my DBs with auto update stats enabled recently started to have some behavioral change.
We do a scheduled nightly stats update and on top of that we have auto update stats. But auto update stats never gets triggered for any of the indexes out of our nightly schedule.
We are now updating 1 column heavily and because of that, auto updates stats is getting triggered for that index multiple times in a day resulting in IO wait and higher response time.
That specific index is not being used in any of our select access patterns, so i am thinking it is safe to disable auto update stats for that Index alone. Is it possible in SQL server 2016?
Do we have more granularity like something we get for auto vacuum in postgres? Please let me know. Thanks for your help

Ok found this .. never tested .. will check this one.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-autostats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN

I mean the index is not being used in any of the queries. It was introduced for data cleanup but we have taken a different direction now. so I am assuming it is safe to disable auto updates stats for that index alone.
Ya i already turned on AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC, which has improved things but still auto update stats whenever triggers does a lot of IO which is expected and query latency is spiking.
